Error using jsonwebtoken Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
I am trying to sign data using jwt.
even the most simple signing throw a runtime error.
for example this code:
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'; const payload = {}  jwt.sign(payload, 'secretKey')
I am using cloudflare worker and my node version is v18.16.0.
I tried to downgrade my jsonwebtoken version to 8.5.1 and run npm update after, it still fail.
If I put value inside the payload or add expire date it's still failing.
I also tried jwt.sign(payload, 'secretKey' ,{ algorithm: 'HS256', allowInsecureKeySizes: true, allowInvalidAsymmetricKeyTypes: true } ) 

Have you added the Node.js compatibility flag to your workers project, like so?
